# How to refer to a command beginning with $?

Tags: bash, history-expansion

Assume that the history list contains the command `e='echo a b c'` and then `$e`.

How to refer to the command `$e` using the history expansion feature of bash?

Comment: @AdminBee !$ refers the last word of the last command. If $e is not the last command, !$ does not work.

Comment: You are right; showcase of a bad testing example :(

Comment: This works for your example: `!?$`, but it searches `$`anywhere in the command, not only in the beginning. So if there is some other command with `$` e.g. `echo "$e"` coming after `$e` ..., you get that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative you can set an alias for:

```bsh
eval `history |awk '/^  [0-9]*  [$]/{print $2}'|tail -n 1`
```

It searches the history for the last command starting with `$` and evaluates the result. Although, it will not work with multiline commands.

I would suggest using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, typing `$`, and cycling through previous commands matching `$`.